# Why I do get an error when installing the psutil package for python?

Tags: python, psutil

I installed pyhton on a windows 64bit machine (Version 3.10). Afterwards I like to install psutil with:

```
python -m pip install psutil
```

but I get following error message:

```
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0.tar.gz (470 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psutil, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psutil
    Running setup.py install for psutil: started
    Running setup.py install for psutil: finished with status 'error'
python :     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
At line:1 char:1
+ python -m pip install psutil
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (    ERROR: Comm... exit status 1::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
     command: 'C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'C:\\Users\\FHBG1244\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9hd47gcx\\psutil_0500efeadf404b148d11c1599b34df08\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__=
'"'"'C:\\Users\\FHBG1244\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9hd47gcx\\psutil_0500efeadf404b148d11c1599b34df08\\setup.py'"'"';f = 
getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; 
setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install 
--record 'C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2fhy6awl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile 
--install-headers 'C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil'
         cwd: C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9hd47gcx\psutil_0500efeadf404b148d11c1599b34df08\
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": 
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import 
io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'C:\\Users\\FHBG1244\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9hd47gcx\\psutil_0500efeadf404b148d11c1599b34df08\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__=
'"'"'C:\\Users\\FHBG1244\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9hd47gcx\\psutil_0500efeadf404b148d11c1599b34df08\\setup.py'"'"';f = 
getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; 
setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install 
--record 'C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2fhy6awl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile 
--install-headers 'C:\Users\FHBG1244\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What is the problem here??

Comment: See the line starting with `error:` in the log you posted. Did these instructions help?

Comment: The error message states "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/". Did you follow the instructions it gave you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install missing package `pip install wheel`

---

2. Install this tools https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

mark this option during the installation =>

[image]

---

3. Restart Your Machine.

---

4. Run this command in cmd `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

---

5. Now You Can Run this command in cmd  `pip install psutil`

---

6. Finally It's up and running ! :-D ;-) Tested now, on my machine(`win10, python 3.10.0, pip 21.3`)! Good Luck ! Best regards :-D

Comment: Could you please mention the size of `cpp build tools`? Installing gigs of build tools is quite annoying.